# Aliases only work in .zshrc?

Tags: bash, shell, alias, zsh

The ones located in /Users/myuser/.oh-my-zsh/plugins do not work (which are the default ones) and also the ones located in .aliases do not work.

Some information on the paths and user configuration.

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh


# User configuration
homebrew=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
export PATH=$homebrew:$PATH
```

before I had this one but it was not working:

```
#export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
```

Please let me know if you any more info would help or if you know what is happening.

Thank you very much!

**Edit:**

enable the plugins you want in your ~/.zshrc (take a look at the plugins/ directory and the wiki to see what’s available)
example: plugins=(git osx ruby)

I didn't understand the instructions to allow the plugins but you have to only choose them one by one by writing the names of the ones you want. 
(Sorry that my question was not that clear and that it was much more simpler than what it seemed)

Comment: What exactly isn't working in what locations?

Comment: @etan-reisner In terminal. I can use the aliases located in .alias and located in .zshrc. I cannot use all of the aliases which are in the plugins of ohmyzsh -> /Users/akawer/.oh-my-zsh/plugins  (which are the plugins and aliases to everything in git, brew, ant, adb, etc)

I did the setup steps in this site (via curl): 
https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the following to your .zshrc.

```
source $HOME/.aliases
```

you can refer to [Setting up aliases in zsh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31216/setting-up-aliases-in-zsh)

Comment: I did that and the .alias commands work but the ones in /Users/myuser/.oh-my-zsh/plugins are still not working.

Comment: Ok no, if I do source $HOME/.alias it doesn't work. It says:

/Users/akawer/.zshrc:source:98: no such file or directory: /Users/akawer/.alias

@gzh

Comment: You can also use source command to refer to the ones located in /Users/myuser/.oh-my-zsh/plugins.

Comment: Please check the pathname to your alias file. you should use /the/path/to/your_alias_file as the argument of source command. @akawer

Answer (score 0):

Enable the plugins you want in your ~/.zshrc (take a look at the plugins/ directory and the wiki to see what’s available) 
example: plugins=(git osx ruby)

I didn't understand the instructions to allow the plugins but you have to only choose them one by one by writing the names of the ones you want. (Sorry that my question was not that clear and that it was much more simpler than what it seemed).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`$HOME/.aliases` is likely to be email aliases, not command aliases 
bash has `~/.bash_aliases` so try `~/.zsh_aliases` or just add them in `~/.zshrc`.